# How to load user via user email?

Tags: 7, nodes, feeds

I am going to import data from a csv file, specifically linking a node to a user. I see that I can link a node to a user via user id, however I won't know the user id on import. Is there a way I can link the node to the user via user email?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ofcourse you can get user id by email, check this out: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_load_by_mail/7

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I am currently trying to learn Drupal and not really sure how to implement this? Can you point me in the right direction? Would I add this to the template.php? Also, does this integrate with feeds importer?

Comment: You should create module for this. Check feed module API for any hooks that you can use for this.